# How to recognize a fill down in Google Sheets apps script and treat it as individual edits for onEdit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some onEdit functions working very well in my sheet, but there is an issue- when someone uses the fill down command (command+D on Mac) to quickly fill in information, onEdit doesn't recognize all the new values as individual edits, so the onEdit code never runs. This is the same problem experienced when copying/pasting in data sets, only in the copy/paste example the very first row is recognized as edits and the ones below are ignored. Is there a common way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following code:

```
function onEdit(e){
 var spd = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
 var edited = e.range.getValues()
 ui.alert(edited)
}
```

It worked as expected and showed me all the values that were edited.
Worked in both case of fill down as well as copy and paste.

Would be helpful if you can paste your code to debug it.

Comment: Sorry for not providing an example- I misunderstood the onEdit event object documentation and was working off that bad assumption. This simple solution worked!